Modifying belongsTo contain condition on the fly?
What I have
In my OrdersTable.php:
$this->belongsTo('OrderStatuses', [
    'foreignKey' => ['order_status_id', 'language_id'],
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'className' => 'OrderStatuses',
]);

The above association generates the following SQL when I find() Orders containing OrderStatuses:
SELECT * FROM
    `order` `Orders`
        INNER JOIN `order_status` `OrderStatuses` ON (
                `OrderStatuses`.`order_status_id` = (`Orders`.`order_status_id`)
            AND `OrderStatuses`.`language_id` = (`Orders`.`language_id`)
        ) WHERE
        `Orders`.`order_id` = 123456

Specifically, OrderStatuses.language_id = (Orders.language_id) selects the status translations in the language of the respective order.
What I want
Select the statuses in the language of the current user, not the language that happens to be set for that given order. So I need to provide a specific language_id, or in other words — join on an integer.
SELECT * FROM
    `order` `Orders`
        INNER JOIN `order_status` `OrderStatuses` ON (
                `OrderStatuses`.`order_status_id` = (`Orders`.`order_status_id`)
            AND `OrderStatuses`.`language_id` = (5)
        ) WHERE
        `Orders`.`order_id` = 123456

And because users can change the language, I need to do this dynamically, based on whatever language_id I have in the environment at any given moment. So while my below attempts took place in the table class itself just to see if what I'm after is at all possible, I will need this to happen outside by (most likely) working with $table->associations() and modifying them on the fly.
What I tried


$this->belongsTo('OrderStatuses', [
    'foreignKey' => ['order_status_id', 'language_id'],
    'conditions' => [
        'OrderStatuses.language_id' => 5,
    ],
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'className' => 'OrderStatuses',
]);

This results in Record not found in table "order":
INNER JOIN `order_status` `OrderStatuses` ON (
  `OrderStatuses`.`language_id` = 5 
  AND (
    `OrderStatuses`.`order_status_id` = (`Orders`.`order_status_id`) 
    AND `OrderStatuses`.`language_id` = (`Orders`.`language_id`)
  )   )



$this->belongsTo('OrderStatuses', [
    'foreignKey' => ['order_status_id', 'language_id'=>5],
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
    'className' => 'CakePHPOpencart.OrderStatuses',
]);

This results in Database Error:
INNER JOIN `order_status` `OrderStatuses` ON (
  `OrderStatuses`.`order_status_id` = (`Orders`.`order_status_id`) 
  AND `OrderStatuses`.`` = (`Orders`.`5`)   )



Update 1

it kinda sounds like you'd want to remove the language_id key from the foreignKey option in your first example

If I don't have the language_id in the association's foreignKey, I am getting:

Cannot match provided foreignKey for "OrderStatuses", got "(order_status_id)" but expected foreign key for "(order_status_id, language_id)"

This is apparently because the primary key of OrderStatusesTable (to which Orders belongTo) is compound, and contains the language_id:
// OrderStatusesTable::initialize()
$this->setPrimaryKey(['order_status_id', 'language_id']);

It comes out of bin/cake bake like that because the actual database table has a compound primary key. And bake, actually, complains:
One moment while associations are detected.
<warning>Bake cannot generate associations for composite primary keys at this time</warning>.

Baking table class for OrderStatuses...

Creating file (…)/OrderStatusesTable.php
Wrote `(…)/OrderStatusesTable.php`


Would be easier if you'd show what SQL exactly you want to generate, but it kinda sounds like you'd want to remove the language_id key from the foreignKey option in your first example. But who knows, maybe you need an OR or something, I don't know. Naturally that could also still result in a "not found", as it's an inner join, so more context might be required here.

@ndm, sorry about that, I updated the question with more info including the full SQLs

Should work if you also configure the binding key for the association, so that it doesn't use the primary key of the target table, eg 'bindingKey' => 'order_status_id'
